# Как отключить колоризацию лога при выводе в файл?

Tags: golang, логирование

Код делает колоризованный вывод в stdout (на windows через ansicolor) и часть данных, в соответствии с указанными loglevel, отправляет также в файл. Но в файл попадают и все ansi коды колоризации. Хотелось бы как-то от них избавиться...

```
import (
    "github.com/shiena/ansicolor"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    logwr "github.com/sirupsen/logrus/hooks/writer"
)

func SetLogger(logLevel log.Level) {
    /* конфигурация логгера  */

    log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{
        ForceColors:     true,
        FullTimestamp:   true,
        TimestampFormat: "01/02 15:04:05",
    })

    log.SetOutput(ansicolor.NewAnsiColorWriter(os.Stdout))
    log.SetLevel(logLevel) 
   
}

func SetHookLogger(logWriter *os.File) {
    /* добавляем хук для записи в файл*/

    log.AddHook(&logwr.Hook{
        Writer: logWriter,
        LogLevels: []log.Level{
            log.PanicLevel,
            log.FatalLevel,
            log.ErrorLevel,
            log.WarnLevel,
            log.InfoLevel,
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: не знаком с go... обычно надо проверить, является ли stdout терминалом и если является, то не включать цвета. гугл по запросу «*go isatty*» выдаёт это: https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty

Comment: На windows tty нет и в этом проблема. В коде стоит ForceColors:     true, для того, чтобы цвет выводился независимо от проверки наличия tty, без этого в cmd колоризация вообще не происходит (). Но вот каких-то других настроек пакета, позволяющих задать для каждого writer'а  свой формат вывода я пока не нашел.

Comment: на win go'шный `isTerminal` в `isatty` реализован через `GetConsoleMode`, так что для cmd он должен работать корректно...

Comment: Я же написал: если не использовать  ForceColors:     true, который отключает проверку на tty - никакой колоризации на винде с логгером logrus вообще нет.

Comment: Да, сама проверка isTerminal корректна. Но колоризация не работает по простой причине: isColored := f.ForceColors || (f.isTerminal && (runtime.GOOS != "windows"))                                                                                                        
 Думаю тут все предельно понятно. На винде logrus заранее отрекается от всех попыток колоризации терминала, если только пользователь не отключит проверку..

Comment: я имею в виду просто сделай `ForceColors: isatty.IsTerminal(os.Stdout.Fd())`...

Comment: Для винды ничего не поменяется.

Comment: мм... да, всё понял... сначала неверно прочитал — думал у тебя проблемы, когда ты пытаешься перенаправить вывод в файл... согласен, в твоём случае оно не поможет...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход в использовании библиотеки go-colorable, которая также добавляет колоризацию вывода в windows (своим путем) и в которой есть обертка для удаления колоризации NewNonColorable(writer):

```
import "github.com/mattn/go-colorable"

func SetHookLogger(logWriter *os.File) {
    /* добавляем хук для записи в файл*/

    log.AddHook(&logwr.Hook{
        Writer: colorable.NewNonColorable(logWriter),
        LogLevels: []log.Level{
            log.PanicLevel,
            log.FatalLevel,
            log.ErrorLevel,
            log.WarnLevel,
            log.InfoLevel,
        },
    })
}
```